# Return value after header

Tags: php

I use the header to allow the user to download a file when he clicks on a button. The below code is in a function.

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename='.date("Ymd",$date).".removethis");

echo $data;

exit();

return true;
```

but i dont catch the return value when calling the function. Is it possible to have a exit() and yet have a return value from the function?

Comment: Code execution stops when it gets to `exit()`; you can't return a value afterwards.

Comment: `exit()` accept return code parameter

Comment: @haim770 - but wouldn't that be passed to whatever had called the PHP process?

Comment: What are your intended result from calling exit()?  perhaps there is another way to get what you need.  You only call exit when you want php to exit and stop processing, it is the absolute end of the current execution.  Because you are returning true after the exit, I suspect that ending execution is not what you intend.

Comment: Yes, it's a process return value, and cannot be used as a function return value. just thought it could be helpful anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The function [`exit()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) will terminate the program immediately. So no code execution is expected after `exit()`;

```
exit(); // program terminates
// not executed
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

No.

You could return true and then call the exit() in the code that called the function, perhaps?

```
$val = theFunction($data);
if ($val) {
    exit;
} else {
    // error or something
}
```